# How To Fix : ValueError: Number of labels=21638 does not match number of samples=13

Tags: python, python-2.7, decision-tree

I am very new to python 2.7 I am trying to run Decision Tree Classifier on my dataset but following a tutorial I face this problem I have first vectorized my features columns and saved it into a array and later saved target column in a array using labelencoder. Please can you explain me how do I fix this Error?

Data :

[image: Data here]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = "C:/Users/ashik swaroop/Desktop/anaconda/Gene Dataset/Final.csv"
datacan = pd.read_csv(dataset)
datacan = datacan.fillna('')
features = datacan[[ 
"Tumour_Types_Somatic","Tumour_Types_Germline",
"Cancer_Syndrome","Tissue_Type", 
"Role_in_Cancer","Mutation_Types","Translocation_Partner",
"Other_Syndrome","Tier","Somatic","Germline",
"Molecular_Genetics","Other_Germline_Mut"]]

 from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

X_dict = features.to_dict().values()
vect = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
X_vector = vect.fit_transform(X_dict)

le = LabelEncoder()
y_train = le.fit_transform(datacan['Gene_Symbol'][:-1])


X_Train = X_vector[:-1]

X_Test = X_vector[-1:] 

from sklearn import tree

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf = clf.fit(X_Train,y_train)    `
```

I am Getting this Error :

```
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf = clf.fit(X_Train,y_train)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-49-fef4fc045a54>", line 4, in <module>
clf = clf.fit(X_Train,y_train)

File "C:\Users\ashik swaroop\Anaconda2\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 739, in fit
X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)

File "C:\Users\ashik swaroop\Anaconda2\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 240, in fit
"number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples))

ValueError: Number of labels=21638 does not match number of samples=12

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-49-fef4fc045a54>", line 4, in <module>
clf = clf.fit(X_Train,y_train)

File "C:\Users\ashik swaroop\Anaconda2\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 739, in fit
X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)

File "C:\Users\ashik swaroop\Anaconda2\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 240, in fit
"number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples))

ValueError: Number of labels=21638 does not match number of samples=12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to understand the error:
It seems that your number of training samples (ie. `np.shape(X_train)[0]`) does not match the number of labels (ie. `np.shape(y_train)[0]`).

When looking at your code I am noticing some inconsistencies. Please refer to the inline comments below.

```
import pandas as pd
from apyori import apriori
dataset = "C:/Users/ashik swaroop/Desktop/anaconda/Gene Dataset/Final.csv"
datacan = pd.read_csv(dataset)
datacan = datacan.fillna('')
features = datacan[[ 
"Tumour_Types_Somatic","Tumour_Types_Germline",
"Cancer_Syndrome","Tissue_Type", 
"Role_in_Cancer","Mutation_Types","Translocation_Partner",
"Other_Syndrome","Tier","Somatic","Germline",
"Molecular_Genetics","Other_Germline_Mut"]]
# EDIT replace by features = [ 
#"Tumour_Types_Somatic","Tumour_Types_Germline",
#"Cancer_Syndrome","Tissue_Type", 
#"Role_in_Cancer","Mutation_Types","Translocation_Partner",
#"Other_Syndrome","Tier","Somatic","Germline",
#"Molecular_Genetics","Other_Germline_Mut"]

orders = datacan[features].to_dict( orient = 'records' ) # this variable is not used

from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

X_dict = features.to_dict().values() # try replacing this line with X_dict = orders
vect = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
X_vector = vect.fit_transform(X_dict)

le = LabelEncoder()
y_train = le.fit_transform(datacan['Gene_Symbol'][:-1])


X_Train = X_vector[:-1]

X_Test = X_vector[-1:] 

from sklearn import tree

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf = clf.fit(X_Train,y_train)
```

Comment: I am sorry that line orders = datacan[features].to_dict(orient = 'records') was there by mistake I didnt use it. And I have tried using the orders dictionary as well stil li get the same error. I am taking Gene_Symbol as a target variable so I dont know how can I take the number of labels same as training sample as it contains all the other variables

Comment: Did you get the same numbers in the mismatch? I edited the comments. Can you retry?

Comment: I actually did work thanks let me see if I am geting the right output or not thank for giving time to this .

Comment: I have tried the same, I dont know why my code throws the error at 

y_train = le.fit_transform(datacan['Gene_Symbol'][:-1])


KeyError: 'Gene_Symbol'

Comment: @MurtuzaHusain it seems `'Gene_Symbol'` is not a column of `datacan`